# Problem with displaying encoded paths in Google Maps Static

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've encoded a polygon's path.

When I check it in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility, it works perfectly :
[Polygon in Google Devlopper Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKoeL.png)

```
encoded path: wptdHtgeI@a@HaEHmCTkDDUVsAF{G@wD@o@~~~~~~Bq@@{CAuC?{D?_B?e@EsCe@aCoA{Ea@}AOm@vAgA|BcBr@i@nCs@hBe@~@UlFmAZI|Cs@nBc@FAf@K`@IAvDFF~~~~~~Bp@@|D~~~~~~BlC@tG~~~~~~BX@hG~~~~~~B`A~~~~~~BzC~~~~~~BfB~~~~~~Bx@~~~~~~B|D~~~~~~B^~~~~~~BtA@`D~~~~~~B`@~~~~~~B~~~~~~BG?B\?bE~~~~~~BrD@jJ@xDEvA~~~~~~Bt@?rA@|F?|E~~~~~~BRIBq@JC@k@Hm@H?~~~~~~BA~~~~~~B@Pq@\{Av@sBbA{ADk@Xi@Hi@G[GUIUGUIMC_EwBWCYEUC~~~~~~B?HiC|@LF@F}@BWNaDNsDc@YuABU@sADH_D~~~~~~BAYFB{@??
```

But when I try the same code with a static map, i doesn't work.

I changed the path with urlencode in PHP :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=YOUR_API_KEY&center=48.109115,-1.670599&zoom=13&size=600x600&maptype=roadmap&path=fillcolor:0xAA000033%7Ccolor:0xFFFFFF00%7Cenc:wptdHtgeI%40a%40HaEHmCTkDDUVsAF%7BG%40wD%40o%40%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EBq%40%40%7BCAuC%3F%7BD%3F_B%3Fe%40EsCe%40aCoA%7BEa%40%7DAOm%40vAgA%7CBcBr%40i%40nCs%40hBe%40%7E%40UlFmAZI%7CCs%40nBc%40FAf%40K%60%40IAvDFF%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EBp%40%40%7CD%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EBlC%40tG%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EBX%40hG%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EB%60A%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EBzC%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EBfB%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EBx%40%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EB%7CD%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EB%5E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EBtA%40%60D%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EB%60%40%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EB%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EBG%3FB%5C%5C%3FbE%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EBrD%40jJ%40xDEvA%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EBt%40%3FrA%40%7CF%3F%7CE%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EBRIBq%40JC%40k%40Hm%40H%3F%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EBA%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EB%40Pq%40%5C%5C%7BAv%40sBbA%7BADk%40Xi%40Hi%40G%5BGUIUGUIMC_EwBWCYEUC%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EB%3FHiC%7C%40LF%40F%7D%40BWNaDNsDc%40YuABU%40sADH_D%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7EBAYFB%7B%40%3F%3F

Please : I need a solution with PHP and not js, and for STATIC maps only...

Comment: I've removed your API key from your question. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Comment: Thanks ! Any suggestion on my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with your encoded path. Use the **resulting encoded polyline** from the [Interactive Polyline Encoder Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility) on your Static Maps API request.

Given your encoded path,

```
wptdHtgeI@a@HaEHmCTkDDUVsAF{G@wD@o@~~~~~~Bq@@{CAuC?{D?_B?e@EsCe@aCoA{Ea@}AOm@vAgA|BcBr@i@nCs@hBe@~@UlFmAZI|Cs@nBc@FAf@K`@IAvDFF~~~~~~Bp@@|D~~~~~~BlC@tG~~~~~~BX@hG~~~~~~B`A~~~~~~BzC~~~~~~BfB~~~~~~Bx@~~~~~~B|D~~~~~~B^~~~~~~BtA@`D~~~~~~B`@~~~~~~B~~~~~~BG?B\?bE~~~~~~BrD@jJ@xDEvA~~~~~~Bt@?rA@|F?|E~~~~~~BRIBq@JC@k@Hm@H?~~~~~~BA~~~~~~B@Pq@\{Av@sBbA{ADk@Xi@Hi@G[GUIUGUIMC_EwBWCYEUC~~~~~~B?HiC|@LF@F}@BWNaDNsDc@YuABU@sADH_D~~~~~~BAYFB{@??
```

you'll have following encoded polyline from the **Interactive Polyline Encoder Utility** which you can use on your Static Maps API request:

```
wptdHtgeI@a@HaEHmCTkDDUVsAF{G@wD@o@?q@@{CAuC?{D?_B?e@EsCe@aCoA{Ea@}AOm@vAgA|BcBr@i@nCs@hBe@~@UlFmAZI|Cs@nBc@FAf@K`@IAvDFF?p@@|D?lC@tG?X@hG?`A?zC?fB?x@?|D?^?tA@`D?`@??G?B\?bE?rD@jJ@xDEvA?t@?rA@|F?|E?RIBq@JC@k@Hm@H??A?@Pq@\{Av@sBbA{ADk@Xi@Hi@G[GUIUGUIMC_EwBWCYEUC??HiC|@LF@F}@BWNaDNsDc@YuABU@sADH_D?AYFB{@??
```

You can try this working API request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=YOUR_API_KEY&center=48.109115,-1.670599&zoom=13&size=600x600&maptype=roadmap&path=fillcolor:0xAA000033%7Ccolor:0xFFFFFF00%7Cenc:wptdHtgeI@a@HaEHmCTkDDUVsAF{G@wD@o@?q@@{CAuC?{D?_B?e@EsCe@aCoA{Ea@}AOm@vAgA|BcBr@i@nCs@hBe@~@UlFmAZI|Cs@nBc@FAf@K`@IAvDFF?p@@|D?lC@tG?X@hG?`A?zC?fB?x@?|D?^?tA@`D?`@??G?B\?bE?rD@jJ@xDEvA?t@?rA@|F?|E?RIBq@JC@k@Hm@H??A?@Pq@\{Av@sBbA{ADk@Xi@Hi@G[GUIUGUIMC_EwBWCYEUC??HiC|@LF@F}@BWNaDNsDc@YuABU@sADH_D?AYFB{@??
```

**Note:** Please provide your own API key on the sample request.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great ! Thanx a lot !

Comment: Sure! Glad I could help. If this solves your issue, you can accept this answer. Thanks!